# Upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10, do-release-upgrade stuck at "Reading Cache"

Tags: upgrade

Running do-release-upgrade, it gets stuck on reading cache

Did a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` before, any ideas?

Edit: Rebooted and decided to let it keep going. Still stuck on reading cache. Search results turning up nothing, can't find anyone that's had a similar problem.

Comment: 'Reading Cache' occurs several times. Which time is this? What happend immediately previous?

Comment: First one that comes up. Here's a screenshot of where i'm at: https://i.imgur.com/vqhXQfc.png.

Comment: Can you specify more information? For examaple the apt log. CLI: cat var/log/apt/history.log
GUI: gedit var/log/apt/history.log

Comment: Cancel and start again. Release upgrades can be safely cancelled at any time during calculation and downloading. Release-upgrades *must not* be cancelled later -- during package installation and configuration.

Comment: I've interrupted it more than a few times. Rebooted too. It never gets past it.

Comment: Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/WhCBL2d.png

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. The screenshot seems to show expected behavior: 'Reading Cache' occurs before any logged actions.

Comment: Well yeah, it going into reading cache is expected behavior. Hanging isn't. I don't know where to find the logs for this, and googling hasn't yielded anything useful either. I'm struggling to pinpoint why it's hanging, hence my post on here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

I also had lots of

`NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s!`

errors in the system logs.

This answer on the Canonical bug tracker: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1530405/comments/75 helped me solve the issue

I switched from nouveau to nvidia drivers, all CPU stuck issues disapeared and the `do-release-upgrade` worked.

Answer (score 0):

So, after messing around since yesterday morning with this, I discovered that all I had to do was run do-release-upgrade with the -p flag for it to proceed past reading cache. Idk why, but it worked and i'm up and running now. If anyone has this problem in the future, try that.

Answer (score 0):

To address another potential cause, I had the exact symptoms posted in the question and for me it was caused by a  customer kernel I was using. Once I switched back to the stock kernel I was able to get passed the reading cache step.